# Terrform Import command error when "Refreshing State"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to import resources from AWS into a simple terraform file.

Terraform file:

```
provider aws {
    access_key = "..."
    secret_key = "..."
    region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "Test_VPC" {

}
```

When I try to import the `Test_VPC`, using `terraform import aws_vpc.Test_VPC vpc-xxxxxxxx` (vpx-xxxxxxxx is a valid VPC ID), I get the following error:

```
aws_vpc.Test_VPC: Importing from ID "vpc-xxxxxxxx"...
aws_vpc.Test_VPC: Import complete!
  Imported aws_vpc (ID: vpc-xxxxxxxx)
aws_vpc.Test_VPC: Refreshing state... (ID: vpc-xxxxxxxx)
Error importing: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_vpc.Test_VPC (import id: vpc-xxxxxxxx): 1 error(s) occurred:

* import aws_vpc.Test_VPC result: vpc-xxxxxxxx: import aws_vpc.Test_VPC (id: vpc-xxxxxxxx): Terraform detected a resource with this ID doesn't
exist. Please verify the ID is correct. You cannot import non-existent
resources using Terraform import.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, if someone else runs into this: The credentials I was using didn't have enough permissions. Running `aws ec2 describe-vpcs -vpc-ids vpc-xxxxxxxx` made that apparent.